# Where is the best branch where install new package on git?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-flow

I'm start using on a self-project git-flow, but I have got a doubt to do a good practise on it when I have two principal branch like  **`master`** and **`develop`**.

**Is it more correct to install the package on a new branch called e.g *`FEATURE install react-redux`*?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your preferred workflow, but a common pattern is to create a new branch (`git checkout -b my-feature-branch`) while working on your feature, install your package there and make any necessary code changes you'd want for the feature. Then you can open a pull/merge request with your feature branch to be merged into `master`, and then merge when you're ready.

Comment: I will do this that you say, it's more clean to search something later on the workflow if something goes wrong.
Thanks a lot for answer so quickly

Answer (score 1):

If you're using git-flow workflow (as tagged), the rules are strict.

I assume this isn't a hotfix but a feature. So you need a feature branch.

In that case you need to create a **new** branch **from develop** and merge it later (with or without a pull request) first back **to develop**.

See this famous image:
[image]

See more about git flow:

- https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/
- https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

Comment: This picture says more than 1000 words. If I don't understand something with the different branches, I look at this picture! Nice Answer!

Comment: Thanks, I added also the original source of that image and full length description. (Funny he advise GitHub flow instead of gitflow nowadays, but that's off topic I think)

Answer (score 0):

I would program everything on the develop branch. From there I would create a new gitflow branch `git flow feature start react-redux` and make all changes in this branch. To **push** changes in this branch, you have to enter following command: `git flow feature publish react-redux` (only for the first push-command, further push-commands can be carried out with `git push`).  When you have finished the project so far, you can close the gitflow branch react-redux and push every change into the develop branch with `git flow feature finish react-redux`. This command will remove the branch **react-reduc** and push all changes into the branch, where you have created the gitflow-branch (in this example in the **develop** branch)

Hopefully it will work that way, I have been using this method for a long time and I am completely satisfied.